# Orchard planting problem for circles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

What is the most number of 4-point circles passing through $n$ points on a plane? This is a variant of the orchard-planting problem that uses circles instead of straight lines. I have [posted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101945/general-orchard-planting-problem-for-circles/) this problem on Puzzling StackExchange, but I feel it is better suited here. I have also started an [integer sequence](https://oeis.org/A337747) with some initial terms. I am interested in lower/upper bounds, proofs of optimality, as well as, actual solutions. I look forward to your answers.